# Connections using during import are not been saved after the import is completed

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, powerapp, power-platform

I am importing a solution inside our live environment the solution is managed >> and during the import i select this connection name/reference "D365PowerPlatformSVC" for all the SharePoint and outlook connections:-

[image: johnjohn123_0-1686775090314.png]

but after the import is done >> i went to the environment variables from the default solution>> and i can see that they are suing the wrong connection name/reference . i tired to changed it back to the correct connection name/reference>> save the changes but when i open it again i got the wrong connection name again??

here is the wrong connection name on all the environment variables.. any advice?

[image: johnjohn123_1-1686775419908.png]

what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this issue in my side, and I did not encounter this problem with you.
Since we can't reproduce your situation, we need to narrow down the problem and try some things:

- Maybe you can try to adopt browser privacy mode or change the browser and re-import the solution.
- Please check that the solution you want to upload is not available in the same environment.

[image]